# mysql update only increments one time

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to create a query that will the increment the values from 1 column and update itself based on the max int value of the same column

```
update
    content
set
    ord = (
        select
            tempOrd
        from
            (
                select
                    max(ord) as 'tempOrd'
                from
                    content
            ) as temp
    ) + 1
where section_id = 'news.article'
```

(edit: removed redundant order by query)

there are 67 entries in the database, if the `max(ord)` is `10118` this will only update the column to `10119` for all entries.

i'm sorta expecting it to do `10119, 10120, 10121, 10122, ...`

Comment: Is `order by ord desc` necessary? To me it is redundant as you just want to update and not fetch.

Comment: Do you want to get the max(ord) of the content with `section_id = 'news.article'` to update another content with `section_id = 'news.article'` or the max(ord) of the whole table to update the new content?

Comment: i have multiple section_id's and I want to target only the ones that have `news.article`. the `max(ord)` is to get the very last ord int of the entire table. from there i want to update the `ord` column for all the `news` sections to be at the top of the `ord`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update content c
cross join (select max(ord) as max_ord from content) mx
cross join (select min(ord) as min_ord from content where section_id = 'news.article') mn
set c.ord = ord + 1 + mx.max_ord - mn.min_ord
where c.section_id = 'news.article'
```

Comment: hi, running this query gives me this: http://droplr.eli007.com/mhaJv2, the left column is the current `ord` the right column is the `ord` the query will update to. is there a way to do this without doublind the ord counts by adding the max ord to the current ord?

Comment: @Eli - I updated my answer. But now i believe that it's not a good idea at all. The question is, why are you doing that?

Comment: ooh, i see what you did there. i'm sorry but i get `unkown column c.section_id in where clause` trying to see whats causing that. but to answer your question i'm trying to not run up the int values of the records. one day it'll hit the 11 int limit ;)

Comment: @Eli "i'm trying to not run up the int values" - But you're doing the opposite :-)